# obtaining the minimum value in an array

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, min

```
 #include <stdio.h>

int min=0;
int find_min_index(int numbers[], int length)
{
for(int a=0; a<length; a++)
{
    if(numbers[a]<min)
    min=numbers[a];
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[])
{
int data_array_1 = ( 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
int data_array_2 = ( 2, -4, 6, -8, 10, -12, 14, -16};
int data_array_3 = ( 6, 4, 1, 4, 5, 3, 2};

printf("Min's index array1 is: %d\n", find_min_index(array1, 6));
printf("Min's index array2 is: %d\n", find_min_index(array2, 9));
printf("Min's index array3 is: %d\n", find_min_index(array3, 7));

return 0;
}
```

the output i am getting is:

Min's index array1 is: 6

Min's index array2 is: 9

Min's index array3 is: 7

while the output i expect is:

Min's index array1 is: 1

Min's index array2 is: -16

Min's index array3 is: 1

cay you guys help me with getting the appropriate results.

Comment: @CoolGuy so what you are saying is that i should add it  in the main function or the "find_min_index"???

Comment: Please indent your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution -

```
   #include <stdio.h>

  int find_min_index(int numbers[], int length)
  {
     int a;                           // bring a and min inside function 
     int min=numbers[0];              // initialize min with array's 1st element  
    for(a=1; a<length; a++)
    {
         if(numbers[a]<min)
         min=numbers[a];
     }
     return min;                       //return min from function 
  }

   int main( int argc, char* argv[])
    {
      int data_array_1[]={ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};      //declare and initialize array 
      int data_array_2[]={ 2, -4, 6, -8, 10, -12, 14, -16};
      int data_array_3[]={ 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 ,0};

      printf("Min's index array1 is: %d\n", find_min_index(data_array_1, 6));   // calling function in printf
      printf("Min's index array2 is: %d\n", find_min_index(data_array_2, 8));
      printf("Min's index array3 is: %d\n", find_min_index(data_array_3, 11));   
   // printf("Min's index array3 is: %d\n", find_min_index(data_array_3, 10));  // in case you need this output as 1

      return 0;
   }
```

**Note-** Don't initialize `min` with `0` as array with `+ve` elements without `0` won't give correct output.

Comment: your final printf should not have a "length" parameter of 11, it should be 10 - since OPs expected output was 1 (11 would give output of 0)

Comment: @JosephDuty I will mention it . Thanks !!

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks  Sir !!  . Fixed that.

Answer (score 2):

1)  You need to return min in your find_min_index, currently there is no return value.

2)  Setting min to 0 wont give you the correct results if there are only > 0 values.
3)  You don't have a close bracket for your find_min_index function, so that should not compile

Answer (score 0):

I do not know how the code you have pasted in you question even compiled (you didn't pass the right arrays, you didn't declare the arrays in the right way - you should specify **size** of the array) but I made it work. The main problem is that you have initialized `min` to 0. You should initialize it to the first element of the array passed to your function as the elements in your array may be negative (consider: `{-1,1,2,3}`).

You were also passing `9` instead of `8` as length of the array:
`printf("Min's index array2 is: %d\n", find_min_index(data_array_2, 9));` (the same applies for the function call with `data_array_3`).

It is better to declare functions that take arrays in C as pointer types, that is: `int find_min_index(int* numbers, int length)`.

Also, the correct output for the given input data will be:

```
Min's index array1 is: 1
Min's index array2 is: -16
Min's index array3 is: 0
```

Here is the fixed version of you function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int find_min_index(int* numbers, int length) {
    int min = numbers[0];
    for (int a = 1; a < length; a++) {
        if (numbers[a] < min) min = numbers[a];
    }
    return min;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int data_array_1[6] = {1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11};
    int data_array_2[8] = {2, -4, 6, -8, 10, -12, 14, -16};
    int data_array_3[11] = {10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0};

    printf("Min's index array1 is: %d\n", find_min_index(data_array_1, 6));
    printf("Min's index array2 is: %d\n", find_min_index(data_array_2, 9));
    printf("Min's index array3 is: %d\n", find_min_index(data_array_3, 7));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think that output is no correct . You see min values in 3rd array is `0` or `1` as OP wants but you get `4` . You should length in the function calls

Comment: @ameyCU Right, it was a typo.

Comment: Having initialised `min` fom the first element, you can start the loop from `1`.

Comment: @WeatherVane yes, you can.

Answer (score -1):

Before your for loop start just initialize `min=0;` It could solve your problem.

Comment: Right now also it is initialized as `0` .

Comment: No, `min` should be initialised either to the first element, or to `INT_MAX`. `0` is wrong answer if all the element values are `> 0`.